# Can you translate the language used to program Lua?

Tags: lua

For example, from English to Spanish. Eg.

```
función miFunción( )
    impresión '¡Hola!'
fin
```

Comment: I think he's asking if you can have Lua with tokens in another non-English language. For education reasons perhaps or something.

Answer (score 2):

Translating the keywords is simple: just edit [luaX_tokens](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/llex.c.html#luaX_tokens). Do *not* reorder that list.

Using other names for functions is also simple and can be done without patching Lua by writing  a Lua script with `impresion=print` etc.

The main problem is using accents. Using a code page like ISO-8859-1 is easy: just edit [lctype.c](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lctype.c.html) and add accented letters as letters. Using UTF8 is hard because Lua is byte oriented. Perhaps it's doable by editing [lctype.c](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lctype.c.html). See [this](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-12/msg00773.html).